# Manage (View & Update) Internal IP address of IIS

Tags: router, wireless-router, port-forwarding, iis, iis-8

How do I figure out the the internal IP address of IIS on the individual PCs?

I have two PCs with IIS (vv 7.5 and 8) on them - I need to configure port forwarding on the router, such that external calls will target the right IIS.

I previously had just one laptop with IIS, which I successfully mapped to my static IP using port forwarding and internal IP - 192.168.0.15. Since I've got another PC which I want to handle requests, so I need to get its IIS's internal IP and adjust port forwarding accordingly.

Comment: 1. Assuming there's only one ip address bound to the machine in question then the ip address that IIS will be using is the ip address of the machine. 2. If you're planning on forwarding port 80 from a single public ip address to multiple internal ip addresses then you're going to need to use something like ARR to do it.

Comment: thanks for that I hope it's easier than that. I have it working now, but it hits the wrong IIS... I presume I can fix it by changing internal IP to the right one in port forwarding. I just need to find out the local IP of the right IIS!

Comment: What's the ip address of the computer? That will be the ip address of IIS on that computer.

Comment: It's currently 192.168.1.15, so I'm hoping the right IIS will have something like 192.168.1.N, just need to find that N...

Comment: ipconfig tells the local IP - but will it reamain the same? I've got no home network or anything...

Comment: You're missing my point. IIS by default runs on the same ip address as the computer, so there is no `N`, unless you add multiple ip addresses to the computer and bind IIS to one of those additional ip addresses.

Comment: How many ip addresses does the computer have?

Comment: I've got your point. Yes the wrong IP is 192.168.1.15, checked the right PC - it has 192.168.1.17. My question now is how sustainable are those addresses? Are they guaranteed to be the same after PCs/Router reboot?

Comment: Are the computers getting those ip addresses via DHCP? If so, then there's no guarantee that the computers will always get the same ip address. You can assign a static ip address to each computer if you need them to always have the same ip address.

Comment: Thanks a million, please post it as answer and I'll accept it:) I'm happy to adjust it manually after rebooting, static IPs will be my next adventure in a few weeks time so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's only one ip address bound to the machine in question then the ip address that IIS will be using is the ip address of the machine.

If you're planning on forwarding port 80 from a single public ip address to multiple internal ip addresses then you're going to need to use something like ARR to do it.

IIS by default runs on the same ip address as the computer unless you add multiple ip addresses to the computer and bind IIS to one of those additional ip addresses.

If the computers are getting those ip addresses via DHCP then there's no guarantee that the computers will always get the same ip address. You can assign a static ip address to each computer if you need them to always have the same ip address